# How to Fix "export 'React' (imported as 'React') was not found in 'react'" Error in React js

Tags: reactjs

When i run react app it shows me `export 'React' (imported as 'React') was not found in 'react'`. Error for all pages [see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE6iM.png).

Comment: Please show us what your import statement looks like in MessageBuilder/index.js (as text, not an image)

Comment: please show your imports

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the errors in the image, you are probably doing this:

```js
import { React } from 'react';
```

This is wrong, because `React` is not a **named export**, it's a **default** export, and you should import default exports like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
```

You can read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).